# Why is my method expecting the wrong return type?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a method that is defined to receive two parameters. One is a generic type, the other is a function with a generic return type:

```
public class MyHelperClass<TRequest, TResponse>
{
   public TResponse Execute(TRequest request, Func<IDataRecord, TResponse> builder){ ... }
}
```

Then I have an object that has a method I want to pass in as a delegate

```
public class MyObject
{
   public TResponse BuildMe(IDataRecord rdr){ ... }
}

//call like this
MyHelperClass.Execute(input, myObjectInstance.BuildMe);
```

but I get an error stating:

"Expected a method with 'TRequest BuildResponse(IDataRecord)'

why is it expecting a TRequest as a return instead of a TResponse??

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this:

```
private GetSamyungDataSourceV1<TRequest, TRequest> _getSamyungDataSourceV1;
```

.. should be:

```
private GetSamyungDataSourceV1<TRequest, TResponse> _getSamyungDataSourceV1;
                                          // ^^^ this.
```

..otherwise, `TResponse` in that class is a `TRequest`.

Comment: oh my good god how did i miss that. rofl. thanks. i just needed another set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Because _getSamyungDataSourceV1 is declared as `GetSamyungDataSourceV1<TRequest, TRequest>` -- its response type is therefore TRequest.  Perhaps the second type argument should be `TResponse` instead.